# How to get 1 character before a specified character

Tags: php

My string `"**7:00am-4:00pm** M-F"`
What I am trying to do is extract the `"7"` and the `"4"`, but those numbers can be different from string to string. 
I have looked up may functions that can find the occurrences of `":"`  but they either return the beginning half, only match the first occurrence, or return true or false.

Comment: I am poopy at RegExp, however I imagine you would use `preg_match_all` to find the digits to the left of `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a good case for regular expressions.  Here is one that should do the trick:

```
<?php 

function get_times($str) {
    preg_match('#\*\*(\d{1,2}):\d\d\w+-(\d{1,2}):\d\d\w+\*\*#', $str, $matches);
    return array($matches[1], $matches[2]);
}

$strs = array();
$strs[] = "**7:00am-4:00pm** M-F";
$strs[] = "**11:00am-1:00pm** M-F";
$strs[] = "**4:00am-11:00pm** M-F";
$strs[] = "**11:00am-11:00pm** M-F";

foreach ($strs as $str) {
    echo $str . "\n";
    list($start, $end) = get_times($str);
    echo "Start: $start, End: $end\n\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
**7:00am-4:00pm** M-F
Start: 7, End: 4

**11:00am-1:00pm** M-F
Start: 11, End: 1

**4:00am-11:00pm** M-F
Start: 4, End: 11

**11:00am-11:00pm** M-F
Start: 11, End: 11
```

**NOTE**
This will work for times with 1 or 2 digits as shown in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function

```
$string = "**7:00am-4:00pm** M-F";

$string = explode(":",$string);

$first  = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", substr($string[0],-2));
$second = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", substr($string[1],-2));
```

And it works double digits times.

Comment: This will only work for one digit times.  For example, what if start time is 11:00am.

Comment: Nope.  You will get 0 and -4 for the example provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+):/', '**7:00am-4:00pm** M-F', $matches); 
$numbers = end($matches); 
$start = $numbers[0];
$end = $numbers[1];
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `strpos()` and subtract 1:

```
$index = strpos($text, ":");

if ($index > 0) {
  $value = substr($test, $index - 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: The OP needs to extract both `7` and `4`. I believe this code will only extract the first instance of `:`

Comment: @njk, umm, ever heard of a loop?  This was just a sample that can be extended.

Comment: Perhaps your answer should mention it?

Comment: @sberry Well, the title of the question is how to get '1 character' before the colon.  But I admit there are better ways to solve the problem.